# Pentaho Data Integration : Combination Lookup/Update : Not all rows inserted

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-data-integration

My question is simple, *I want to know why not all my rows inserted to my PostgresDB*. Because I need all rows inserted. The step (Combination L/U) is got succeeded with green tick mark. Shouldn't the step got red tick mark on it if it's not successful? Here is the step metrics of my transformation :

[image: Transformation Step :]

[image: Combination L/U configuration :]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the combination lookup/update step's configuration? It's most likely that some of your records have identical values for all the lookup fields, so the lookup doesn't need to change anything, it only returns the key for the existing dimension record.

Comment: I have add a screenshot of the combination L/U step, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are filling a fact table, not a dimension. A Table Output step is the correct choice for that, as you don't need to look anything up anymore, you already did that in the previous steps.

A note about your data and the fact table:

From the question, you have some duplicate rows (the ones disappearing in the combination lookup update). Please check carefully whether they should be there according to the source data and whether they obey the "granularity" you have in mind.

For example:

- if the fact table contains one record per sale, it's perfectly fine for there to be two rows with the same time, office, etc, and even the same amount. Your table does contain a lot though, almost 10%.
- if the fact table contains the sales per day per office, etc. Then there should **NOT** be two rows with all the same keys and even same amounts. It's likely some join operation in the ETL created duplicates.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, it is indeed a fact table. I just happen to realize i can use table output for my fact table because i already do all the lookup i need. As i examine the source file, you were right, it is contains some duplicate rows for the combination i lookup. So, the 130k rows is already the right number for my fact table. Thanks.